# Convergence in distribution for sum of products of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, probability-limit-theorems

Given a martingale difference sequence $X_i$ with $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \implies N(0,\Sigma)$, where $\implies$ denotes convergence in distribution, and $\Sigma$ is some covariance matrix. Let $Y_i$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with mean 0, variance 1, independent of $X_i$. Is it true that $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i Y_i \implies N(0,\Sigma)$?

Comment: If $Y_i$ can depend on $X_i$ then not necessarily, since we can suppose $\{X_i\}$ are i.i.d. mean 0 variance 1 Gaussian random variables, and define $Y_i=X_i$ for all $i$.  Then $\{Y_i\}$ are i.i.d. mean 0 variance 1, but $\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i\geq 0$ surely.

Comment: I don't think this is true even if the $\{Y_i\}$ variables are independent of $\{X_i\}$.

Comment: $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are independent of each other, and $X_i$ is mean 0 (actually, it's a martingale difference sequence). I will make these edits to the post.

Comment: Your edit added the martingale assumption on $\{X_i\}$ but still allows $Y_i=X_i$.  My particular counter-example for $\{X_i\}$ and $\{Y_i\}$ independent goes away when you add the assumption that $\{X_i\}$ is a martingale difference sequence.